# How can i pass a reference to a html-node without using css-selecors?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I used to target a html-node like this:

```
new graph(".version .generalConversion")
```

I'm now trying to make a more general approach that applies to all instances with the class graph.

```
var graphs = d3.selectAll('.graph');
    graphs[0].forEach(function(leGraph){
        new graph(this)
    });
```

However, "this" doesn't work. How can I pass a reference to a html-node without using css-selectors?

Comment: I would refactor `graph` to take a node or D3 selection. Also, you probably want `d3.selectAll(".graph").each(function() { new graph(this); })`.

Comment: How would I that? Like how do I make a d3-selection and pass it to the function? Or a node for that matter.

Comment: That's what you're doing in the code you have -- `this` is a reference to the DOM element (the node in the DOM).